# Why Retina screenshots are twice as large as chosen area?

Tags: macos, display, screen-capture

This is a known issue, but I do not understand why the screenshot taken on *my* retina-MBP always has doubled size as compared to area chosen for screenshot:

If I choose 100x100 (as OS shows - of what? pixels? - on "get info" they do not provide, only shows "dimensions") area I get 200x200 which upon scaling becomes more blurry than original picture.

My questions:

1. Do all retina users always get these doubled screenshots?
2. How can I take a screenshot of the same size as the area I choose?

I found a lot of "resizing" solutions, but is there a way to take a screenshot with "original size" without resizing the resultant screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes - that's the way it's coded/engineered
2. No - you'll need to post process the images using a tool that's designed to automate this or use Automator to make a service to resample the images.

I like [Skitch](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch-snap.-mark-up.-share./id425955336?mt=12) and [Napkin](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/napkin-image-annotation-markup/id581789185?mt=12) for processing retina images, but there are many others.

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you please comment about "additional issue" I added to the question - it is very important for me, because I feel I cannot work effectively on Retina.

Comment: Let's revert that edit and ask a separate question with just that pixelmatr issue, @Ilan . We strongly prefer one question per question but since yours were a bit easy - I tried for letting both run the first time. You can click on the edit link and see the text to copy/paste and then tag/edit the new question...

Comment: If you believe this is a separate issue and the question will not be marked as duplicate I will be glad to ask another Q.

Comment: Go for it @Ilan - you're asking how to use pixelmator - not at all what this post is covering :-)